# Setting Up Python (in Visual Studio Code) on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows

So I installed the latest version of python (3.9) on my Win10 computer from python.org. I had to set the environment variables manually. Pip finally ran correctly but every time I type python into the command window it drags you off to the Windows store and asks you to install python 3.9. I finally found a post that said things would run if you just typed py in the command window and that did work. I then went on to try and set up Visual Studio Code for python and despite having the correct path to the interpretter, it refused to run and kept saying the path to the interpretter was invalid. I finally found py.exe in the C:\Windows directory and since changing the interpretter path to c:\Windows\Py.exe VS code runs. I would prefer to use the correct path. How do I get Windows to recognize python from the command line and not whisk me off to the Windows store? I suspect if I could get that right, then I could use the correct path to the python installation on my machine in VS code.

Answer (score 0):

Add python 3.9 to your path; windows is detecting another python located somewhere else.

Comment: I already have the python 3.9 directory in the path. I know it is because it can find modules I’ve downloaded with pip that wouldn’t be part of any standard implementation. The only explanation I can think of is that it is finding something earlier in the path that sends it off to the windows store, presumably something in the windows directory. I could alter the order of the paths so it checks my python 3.9 directory before windows, but I am a little loathe to do that

Comment: The path is WindowsApps i am pretty sure please move it up the path thing